# Adding Metadata to Excel File using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am writing an application that requires exporting data to an excel file (and later re-importing that data after some changes). However, the way the excel file is generated does not guarantee a set amount of columns, depending on what is being exported. To remedy this, I intend on adding metadata to the excel file itself, hidden from the user, so I know what to expect upon import. Is there any way to do this using EPPlus?

Comment: Maybe I could use something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx

But I don't think this is supported by EPPlus. Rather, this would be something used in Interop?

Comment: Epplus may or may not pickup that custom part but you might be able to access it using the XML property that is exposed with each Epplus object.  But why cant you just use Epplus's Workshett `Columns` collection/properties to determine how many to iterate over?  Might what to show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: In a similar scenario, I used a "Very Hidden" sheet to store metadata with EPPlus. A Very Hidden sheet cannot be unhidden through normal means in the Excel interface so it was a good workaround to store some metadata. Not sure if that meets your needs.

Comment: @singularhum Yes, the problem is to hide the metadata to prevent modifications from the end user and only be used to aid with parsing the Excel file.